# Subsetting different Countries

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

From a dataframe of 4960 rows, which one is countries, I filtered the top five that appear the most this way, and it works perfectly.

```
sort(table(gtd$country_txt), decreasing = TRUE)[1:5]
```

Now I want to grab all the data from those by subsetting. I already found the way to get 1, but not the 5.

```
gtd_top <- subset(gtd, country_txt == "Afghanistan")
```

It should be Afghanistan, Iraq, Nigeria, Yemen, and India.

Would be better to merge all in 1 function.

Answer (score 2):

Consider passing the names from that sorted vector generated from `table` into `subset` using `%in%`:

```r
top_five <- sort(table(gtd$country_txt), decreasing=TRUE)[1:5]

gtd_top <- subset(gtd, country_txt %in% names(top_five))
```